# Issue while installing ODI with JDK and using jreLoc

Tags: java

It has been a week since I am trying to install ODI  ( oracle data integrator ) , but I failed each time !!! 
I've seen all forums, I've tried everything even the setup.exe jreLoc but it doesn't work !!! Please help me I am losing my mind over this !!! 
I used this command line " setup.exe -jreLoc C:\Program Files\Java after being redirected to the folder where there the disk1 , ( the install of odi )  but it fails with this message " please install java runtime " though it is already installed  what can I do ? I used 64 bit jre /jdk and I am installing ODI 64 bit ( oracle data integrator )

Comment: First, please use less exclamation marks. Second, could you please post *exact* command line you are using, exact java home path and exact error message?

Comment: What is your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set to?

Comment: Hi David , it is set to : C:\Program Files\Java !!

Comment: David and everyone, it is solved thank you! I hope I will not find another problem I used my computer and I did the same thing jreLoc etc. and it works, when I used the laptop of work, I did not have privileges administrator, because it is defined like that from the company sopra ! I will write an article in my blog about the configuration and the install of ODI because there are a lot of bugs  (y) :) !

Comment: Well done, finding the solution.  If you do write an article for your blog, could you perhaps post a link to it here?  It may be useful to other people who stumble across this question.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay yes , of course so don't close it I will write it today and add screenshots and share it in a comment here :-)

Comment: That would be fantastic.  You can even write it as an answer to your own question, if you like, and then "accept" it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are for a windows 7 and a windows 10 environment

I found several problems around the matter:

1) JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME variables are not recognised

2) JRE without JDK does not seem to work

3) space in the path name of the JDK does not work

In all casese you end up with this error:
Invalid JDK passed. Please specify JDK location ( Ex. /home/jdk ), /bin/java should exist.

Solution: create a shortcut to setup.exe, add "-jreLoc" and 
add the path to your JDK, in my case: -jreLoc E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_212

Answer (score 0):

Enter the command as slight different as

```
setup.exe -jreloc C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue:

1. Download Java SE Development Kit 8u261 from [www.oracle.com](https://www.oracle.com/ru/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)
   that is a file `jdk-8u261-windows-x64.exe`
2. Before that I had only jre1.8.0_251 which was installed by default location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`, so I didn't touch it, do not need to uninstall.
3. Now install jdk-8u261-windows-x64.exe, but choose another location without any spaces in it: `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_261` and `C:\Java\jre1.8.0_261` for JRE when it ask to install
4. Open the command prompt, go to the ODI setup file location and start it like that:

   ```
   cd C:\SETUP\ODI Studio 11.1.1.7.0\V37940-01\odi\Disk1\install\win64
   setup.exe -jreLoc C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_261
   ```
5. You must use JDK not JRE to start ODI installation.
6. For the further installation I used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mm5iqoAWCbs
7. Also I had a problem during installation, to fix it you need to edit file
   `C:\SETUP\ODI Studio 11.1.1.7.0\V37940-01\odi\Disk1\stage\prereq\win64\refhost.xml`
   and insert a line with your OS version:

   ```
   <OPERATING_SYSTEM>
     <VERSION VALUE="10.0"/>
   </OPERATING_SYSTEM>
   ```